# Center text vertically next to a one row textarea?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

**I want the text that sits next to a one row textarea to be centered vertically with the textarea.**

This is the default behavior if I put text next to an input of `type="text"`.

Id like to stick with the single row textarea rather than an input here because this field is there for the user to paste a fair amount of pre formatted data into. The user wont normally care what the data says or need to see it unless the program finds a problem. If a problem is found an error is shown, at which point its helpful if the user can drag out the text area to view the data and research the issue.

**My Code:**

```
<tr>
<td class="vert" > New PNR Info
  <textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="origInfo1" id="origInfo1" style="overflow:hidden"> </textarea></td>
<td align="center">Change Fee
  <input type="text" size="4" id="fee"name="fee"></td>
</tr>
```

**Ive Tried:**

css like this:

```
.vert {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and this `vertical-align: top;`

and wraping the two in a p tag like this

```
<p>New PNR Info<textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="origInfo1" id="origInfo1" style="overflow:hidden"> </textarea></p>
```

to no avail.

If my question is not clear maybe a screenshot will help. I want the offending text by the red arrow to be cetered like the text by the green arrow.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like tabular data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem logical at first, but the vertical-align property needs to go on the taller element:

http://jsfiddle.net/N5NuA/

```
textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Man that did not even occur to me, very counter-intuative. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Apply the vertical alignment to all elements like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2QQt/)

```
<p class="whatever">
    <label for="alignme">Label Text</label>
    <textarea id="alignme"></textarea>
</p>

.whatever * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`.whatever *` is equivalent to

```
.whatever label, .whatever textarea  {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: going with cimmanon's answer for simplicity but this also worked and the `.whatever *` part is a great shortcut that I was unaware of, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you are setting the parent (td or p) to align to the top and since your textarea is inside that element it aligns according to parent, not the text.

What I think will work is setting the textarea vertical alignment.

```
<textarea style="vertical-alignment:middle">
```

If that does not work, also change the parent element to middle. Also try text-top or text-bottom for the text-area if those changes do not work also.